# For Loop in Python 3.0

Tags: python

So, I have a really weird question that has kinda always bugged me.  In this example:

```
patterns = [ 'this', 'that' ]
text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'

for pattern in patterns:
    print('Looking for "%s" in "%s" ->' % (pattern, text))
```

So this is just a example, but what I'm wondering, is in the for loop, pattern was never declared, and I know that Python is a dynamic language so you dont have to declare variables, but how does python like know what it means? I've seen this alot with for loops and alot of the time it just seems like people put whatever they want in that part of the for loop, and I really don't get it. Does it matter what you put there?

Comment: Why does your title mention "3.0"? That code is a syntax error in Python 3.

Comment: Pattern was declared the moment you wrote it in the for statement. Other languages do the same thing. See the for each loop in C++.

Comment: i said 3.0 cuss every other for loop question title was taken, and lol yeah that print statement needs parenthesis

Comment: That is how it works - [Python Language Reference 8.3. The for statement](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).  You can use any name you want for the *target* - preferably something expressive.

Comment: How does it know what it means? Because the interpreter decides what meaning is. In this case it sees a *for ... in ....* pattern. It checks if `patterns` has an `__iter__` method. If it does it expands the expression and for each index in `patterns` it assigns `patterns[i]` to `pattern`. It could just as easily see this pattern and decide to do something completely different like write the result to a file called `patterns`, but that wouldn't very obvious or useful would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for` loops, you're iterating over what is in patterns. What it will do is assign the first object in the list `patterns` to the variable `pattern`. And then do it again with the next object.

If you run that code, you get the following output:

```
Looking for this in Does this text match the pattern?
Looking for that in Does this text match the pattern?
             ^
             |
```

The arrow points to the variable `pattern`, which changes every time the loop restarts. I should also point out that this is how the for loop runs in basically every language, including C, Java and Python.

Another simple example to demonstrate this would be to iterate over a python list of integers, done through the `range()` function:

```
for i in range(5):  # range creates this: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```